# How can I use injector for all pages in browser in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I can injector fingerprint only for one page

```
const page = await newInjectedPage(
    browser,
    {
        // constraints for the generated fingerprint
        fingerprintOptions: {
            devices: ['mobile'],
            operatingSystems: ['ios'],
        },
    },
);
```

But how can I add fingerprint when new page open in browser?